# How to copy paste cells using formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells, if

I want the excell to recognize if it is electrical or civil or plumbing and re-arrange the value in order

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: It is very unclear what exactly it is you want to achieve. At a guess, look into SUMIF, COUNTIF, VLOOKUP and/or INDEX/MATCH

Comment: Or a simple pivot table will do this.

Answer (score 0):

As `Scott Craner` says, a "one-layer-of-effort" pivot table would do this for you.

Of course, that's a whole new thing to learn, formatting the things can be a pain, and there's the whole updating, especially if sent to someone, thing. And so on.

What will easily solve it for you with formulas is:

```
=SORT(  FILTER(  $H$2:$H$7,  $G$2:$G$7=K$1  ))
```

`FILTER()` will collect the items that meet the condition. The condition is that some items match the column header. One might think that has to be accomplished by the two things operating on the same range, but it does not:  you can collect things from one range (column H in your case) but do the condition's test on a whole different range (column G in your case). That way you only get items from column H returned, not the column G items as well.

After getting a set of results for a column in your output area, `SORT()` sorts them. It sorts ascending (lowest to highest) here, but can be made to sort in other ways as well. You seem to want ascending so...

The outputs are arrays populating down the column. If you have an earlier version of Excel, or users who do, you'd want to use the `{CSE}` form of entry.

The formulas are one per column, so you have to paste them into the first row of each column.

(In the time I had, I was unable to make a version that could populate the whole table work.)

You can "slickify" your output if you like. You can apply `UNIQUE()` to your name column to find all the headers your output table needs. That will be a vertical result so you need to rotate it to horizontal. `TRANSPOSE()` will handle that nicely. (So could `INDEX()` and it can rotate things all four ways, not just two, but it'd be overkill here, and also not easy to understand a year from now when you upgrade the file.)

To get the names into the header row in sorted order, use `SORT()` again, but use it INSIDE the `TRANSPOSE()` or it will have no effect:

```
=TRANSPOSE(  SORT(  UNIQUE(G2:G7)  ))
```

Back to pivot tables for a moment. If you plan to use Excel for much involving presentation or various summations, not to mention being able to instantly change the output, learning at least pivot table basics would be very useful to you. Worth doing.